# Recovering local git repository from .git

Tags: git

I have a local git repository that is not pushed onto any git repository hosting sites. I have several commits on this repository.

Today, when running `git status`, I get the error 
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Running `ls -a`, I can still see the .git repository and examining the .git/logs/HEAD file, I can also see all of my previous commits.

I would like to recover git in this repository so that I can still revert back to previous commits.

Comment: Which command do you use to see the previous commits?

Comment: I'm simply cd'ing into the .git/logs folder and using vim to read the HEAD file.

Comment: What do you get if you run `git` from the command line? No matter from which directory.

Comment: I get the git usage information. Such as `usage: git [--version] ...`

Comment: Ok, that's good. From the directory where your `.git` is. What do you get if you run `git remote get-url origin`

Comment: What version of `git` do you have? What’s the output of `GIT_TRACE=1 git status`?

Comment: @caramba `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @caramba It sounds like the repository has never interacted with a remote, so I’d expect nothing useful there.

Comment: @DanielH the same. `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Even with `GIT_TRACE`? Huh. What version of Git do you have (`git --version`)?

Comment: @DanielH yep, I think so, just wanted to be sure before breaking something.

Comment: git version 2.7.4

Comment: Oops, I had the wrong variable; there are multiple `TRACE` variables. Do you get anything more if you use `GIT_TRACE_SETUP` instead?

Comment: @DanielH as in `GIT_TRACE_SETUP=1 git status`? I still get the same fatal error message.

Comment: @mas4 I was hoping for at least some other message first as a hint to what was going wrong. What is the result of `ls -l .git`?

Comment: COMMIT_EDITMSG, description, HEAD, /hooks, /info, /logs, /objects

Comment: No `refs` or `branches` directories? No `config` file?

Comment: No, I do not see those

Comment: 1. Make a backup of the folder in case anything gets broken worse. 2. What happens if you run `mkdir -p branches refs/heads refs/tags` and then try a Git command?

Comment: (I mean that you should run the `mkdir` command inside the `.git` directory)

Comment: It looks like it reinitialized git. Running git status, `on branch master. Initial commit`. And all files are untracked.

Comment: I'd still like to be able to go back to old commits but so far, it doesn't seem to be able to recognize that there are older commits.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd still like to be able to go back to old commits but so far, it doesn't seem to be able to recognize that there are older commits

If [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is not showing you anything... you would need to add, commit and push without being able to get your old history back, unfortunately.

But if `git reflog` shows you old commits, you can reset your `master` branch to the most recent one.

Make sure you are not running your command from the `.git` folder itself, but from the parent folder of `.git`.